# Avira alert for js/wmd.js - false alarm?

Tags: support

My Avira antivirus program keeps alerting me about "HTML/Rce.Gen3" in wmd.js on this site. Is that just a false positive? It doesn't happen on stackoverflow.com, only this site, possibly starting when i logged in via Facebook.

Comment: nod32 version 4 report nothing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VirusTotal says the URI is [safe](https://www.virustotal.com/url/743b1b9216416136abdcd59c2ef1c4178182d00b9126db3e16f7a5e6e9abbf4a/analysis/1336130855/), yet the downloaded file is not, according to [1/42 scanners](https://www.virustotal.com/file/74308029dc5820a6b46f2e23ed200b75915702bb7d7e1d76b9e9e9a2618970f5/analysis/) (Avira).

So 41/42 scanners say it's safe. I've submitted a false positive report to Avira, to which they replied:

> The file 'wmd.js' has been determined to be 'FALSE POSITIVE'. In
>   particular this means that this file is not malicious but a false
>   alarm. Detection will be removed from our virus definition file (VDF)
>   with one of the next updates.